# If condition not passing proper value in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to use if condition in embers js. But value not passing properly.

**If Condition**

```
 {{#each item.model }}
     {{#ifCond item.title Raja}}
     <div>equal to</div>
     {{else}}
     <div>not equal to</div>  
     {{/ifCond}}
     {{/each}}
```

**This my HandleBar**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function (v1, v2, options) {

    alert(v1);

    if (v1 === v2) {
        return options.fn(this);

    }
    return options.inverse(this);
});
```

my problem is alert showing value  **item.title**

But I want value sample.

Here my Json

```
posts = [{
    title: "sample",
    body: "There are lots of à la carte software environments in this world."
}, {
    title: "Broken Promises",
    body: "James Coglan wrote a lengthy article about Promises in node.js."
}];
```

Comment: shouldn't it be just title? `ifCond title Raja` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to evaluate values using the current context within the helper.

**Example**,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dixokezafe/1/edit?html,js

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
{{#each model }}
 {{#ifCond title Raja}}
 <div>equal to</div>
 {{else}}
 <div>not equal to</div>  
 {{/ifCond}}
 {{/each}}

 <button {{action "addObject"}}> add random object</button>
```

**js**

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return posts;
  }
});

App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({

  actions:{
    addObject:function(){
      this.get("model").pushObject({
    title: Math.floor(Math.random()*2)===0?"Raja":"something else",
    body: "James Coglan wrote a lengthy article about Promises in node.js."
});
    }
  }

});

var posts = [{
    title: "sample",
    body: "There are lots of à la carte software environments in this world."
}, {
    title: "Broken Promises",
    body: "James Coglan wrote a lengthy article about Promises in node.js."
},
            {
    title: "Raja",
    body: "James Coglan wrote a lengthy article about Promises in node.js."
}];

Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function (v1, v2, options) {

  var _v1 = Em.get(this,v1);
  var _v2 = Em.get(this,v2);
v1 = Em.isEmpty(_v1)?v1:_v1;
  v2 = Em.isEmpty(_v2)?v2:_v2;
    if (v1 === v2) {
        return options.fn(this);

    }
    return options.inverse(this);
});
```

It seems that it is not possible to register a bound helper and use it in block form. Checkout some links with interesting approaches tackling this issue.

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/a-way-to-let-users-define-custom-made-bound-if-statements/2583

https://gist.github.com/slindberg/9924116

http://paarsgames.nl/2014/02/02/creating-your-own-custom-handlebars-bounded-ifs-in-ember/

Comment: hi melc.if u have a time please see my stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27148706/second-dropdown-not-calling-everytime-based-on-first-drop-down

Answer (score 0):

If you are using handlebars version 2 you can just create operators and use the core if helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('eq', function (lhs, rhs) {
    return lhs == rhs;
});
```

Usage:

```
{{#if (eq title "Raja")}}
    <div>equal to</div>
{{else}}
    <div>not equal to</div>  
{{/if}}
```