# How to set Default Value in Ember js

Tags: ember.js

Using Below code i have created Ember View.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
        <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>    
        {{outlet}}
    </script>    
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">    
    <div>
        {{view  "select"  content=model    prompt="Please select a name"  selectionBinding="controllers.comboBox.model"  optionValuePath="content.title" optionLabelPath="content.body"  }}
    </div>
    <div>
      {{view  "select"   content=model1    prompt="Please select a name"  optionValuePath="content.title"  optionLabelPath="content.title" }}
    </div>      
</script>
```

and **App.Js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create({

});

App.Router.map(function () {

});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return posts;
    }
});

App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ["comboBox"],
    sendValueToServer: function () {       
        document.getElementById("comboval").value = this.get("controllers.comboBox.model.title");
    }.observes("controllers.comboBox.model"),


    model1: function () {   

        var valueq = this.get('controllers.comboBox.model.title');
        console.log("value "+valueq);      
        return posts1;  
    }.property("controllers.comboBox.model")
});

App.ComboBoxController = Em.Controller.extend({
    model: null,
});

App.ComboBox1Controller = Em.Controller.extend({
    model1: null,  
});
posts = [{
    title: "Raja",
    body: "There are lots of à la carte software environments in this world."
}, {
    title: "Broken Promises",
    body: "James Coglan wrote a lengthy article about Promises in node.js."
},
{
title: "Broken",
body: "James Coglan wrote a lengthy article about Promises in node.js."
}

];


posts1 = [{
    title: "Raja",
    body: "There are lots of à la carte software environments in this world."
}, {
    title: "Broken Promises",
    body: "James Coglan wrote a lengthy article about Promises in node.js."
},
{
    title: "Broken",
    body: "James Coglan wrote a lengthy article about Promises in node.js."
}

];
```

Above code using Prompt I was showing **"Please select a name"** Default Value.

but Initially i dont want **Please select a name** default value.

my requirement is  need to show second value as a   default value.

how can i do this.

Comment: Two recommendations: show the minimal amount of code that explains your problem and provide a fiddle link. Also, I'm not 100% sure of what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In association to the question mentioned here,
[Second dropdown not calling EveryTime Based on First drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27148706/second-dropdown-not-calling-everytime-based-on-first-drop-down)

To set a default value all it is required is to set a value to the bound property of the specific drop down.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/loqivasova/1/edit

**js**

```
App.ComboBoxController = Em.Controller.extend({
    model: posts[0],
});
```

if however it is required to also modify the second drop down based on this default value, then just add `on("init")` to the `setComboBox1Model1` function,

**js**

```
  setComboBox1Model1:function(){
    var valueq = this.get('controllers.comboBox.model.title');
    var valueFromPosts1 = posts1.findBy("title",valueq);
    this.set("controllers.comboBox1.model1",valueFromPosts1?valueFromPosts1:null);
  }.observes("controllers.comboBox.model").on("init")
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jogaqinugi/1/edit?html,js,output

If it is required to set the value after the view has rendered, then you should use a view

**js**

```
App.IndexView = Em.View.extend({
  setDefaulValue:function(){

    this.set("controller.controllers.comboBox.model",posts[0]);
  }.on("didInsertElement")
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qugefipefi/1/edit?html,js,output